# VS code+JavaScript shortcut for end line with a semicolon and go to the next line

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here is example of what I want to do:

[image: From this]
[image: to this]

I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in WebStorm but now I'm stuck with finding the equal shortcut at VsCode. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you will need to set up a macro for that, it isn't built-in.  See [vscode macro extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros).

And this in your settings:

```
"macros": {

    "insert semicolon and goto next line": [

        "cursorLineEnd",
        {
          "command": "type",
          "args": {
            "text": ";"
          }
        },
        "editor.action.insertLineAfter"
    ]
}
```

Set up a keybinding for that:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+;",
  "command": "macros.insert semicolon and goto next line"
},
```

Comment: You're welcome, and remember to accept the answe if it was helpful,

Comment: Just used Ctrl + Enter as below answer suggested and it seems like a better solution than a macro

Comment: @Ivan Ctrl+Enter just goes to the next line (same as the `insertLineAfter` command I used above).  But the OP wanted to jump to the end of the current line, add a `;` and then go to the next line.  Look at the OP's example.  That is two steps that Ctrl+Enter does not do.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and I solved with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [Auto Insert Semicolon](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lizheng.auto-insert-semicolon) extension.

Work fine for me.**Shortcut:** `alt+enter`