# VS Code insert semicolon at the end of the line and create a new line

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

## What do I want

It is just for comfort but I am searching for a feature in VSCode to insert a semicolon at the end of the current line, while the cursor is still in the middle of the statement. IntelliJ has that Feature. (`crtl + shift + enter`)

## What I have tried so far:

- Installed and enabled IntelliJ IDEA Keybindings.

  - The problem I have is that `crtl + shift + enter` does only complete the statment if autocomplete has an suggestion. But there is no suggestion add semicolon at the end of the line.
  - `shift+ crtl + enter` does start a new line but there is still no semicolon at the end

If I you need more information please let me know...

Comment: with the extension `Multi Command` you can group commands and set a keybinding to this new command, to type `;` use the command: `type`

Comment: Isn't https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50703124/vs-codejavascript-shortcut-for-end-line-with-and-go-to-the-next-line/50705187#50705187 an exact duplicate?  It had a poor title so it is difficult to discover,  I will edit it soon.

Comment: @Mark yes it is related. But I didn't find it because it was for webstorm and I searched for Java with IntelliJ. Thats why I was not abel to find it.

Comment: No worries, it was written oddly so probably only I could have found it.  I have edited it some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to rioV8 for the help with Multi Command.

I added the following snippet to the settings.json:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [
        {
            "command": "multiCommand.addNewLine",
            "sequence": [
                "cursorEnd", 
                {"command": "type", "args": {"text": ";\n"}}

            ]
        }
    ]
```

Than I was able to bind a keybinding to that command in the keybindings.json.